# What markup language do .url files use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, file-format

I have a `.url` file like so:

```
[internetShortcut]
url=http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

When I double-click on this file, it opens a link in my browser to Stack Overflow, as it should.

I incorrectly thought that the format of this file was [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/), but it's not - quotes cannot surround the url given under `internetShortcut.url`.

What is the format of the file, and how can I best parse it (in NodeJS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Microsoft [Internet Shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/internet-shortcuts), originally developed to store Internet Explorer favourites. I presume you're supposed to use Windows APIs to interact with it rather than writing your own parser.

In the context of the Node ecosystem, there seem to be [some implementations](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=internet%20shortcut), probably because the format is not complicated and was easy to support.

Answer (score 1):

Well that didn't take very long.

Turns out that the file format was the good ol' `.ini` file format.

I've been messing around too much with Go and Rust lately, and that's changed my train of thought to the reverse of what is regular (first thinking of INI, rather than TOML :P)

To anyone else needing to parse `.url` files in JavaScript, the [`ini`](https://github.com/npm/ini) package is a good idea: https://github.com/npm/ini.